# Get first class of element

Tags: javascript

So let's I have a `div` with multiple classes like this:

```
<div class="s1 s"></div>
```

In the javascript I only want the first class, like

```
$(document.body).on('click','.s',function(){
   var firstClass = //only get s1 from that one whole class.
});
```

How can I do this?

Comment: This is a bad idea. The DOM does not have a concept of a "first" class, all class names on an element are treated equally. If you do this then your code will work against the expectations of pretty much every other developer and will attract bugs. What's the real problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: @Jon Yep, sounds like another classic case of the XY problem. This seems like an entirely terrible idea.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: inside of that `div` I have another `div class='s1_info'` and I only need the 's1' string so I can form `s1_info` so I can append something to the new formed class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('.s').click(function()
{ 
  var firstClass = $(this).attr('class').split(" ")[0];
});
```

Comment: great answer, it worked, thank you, I will accept it in 10 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
var firstClass = this.className.split(" ")[0];
```

No need to wrap it back into a jQuery element and incur the performance cost.